# How is it possible to deliver email from qmail to a LMTP server?

Tags: qmail, lmtp

I have a *qmail* server, which cannot be changed into anything else, because it is part of a much larger system. It should route all emails to a [Zarafa](http://www.zarafa.com/) server, which only uses the LMTP protocol and to which I don't have physical access.

How is it possible to make qmail deliver the emails to the LMTP server?

Comment: Also, could someone please create the tag _lmtp_? Thanks!

Comment: And maybe the question should be migrated to ServerFault? (if that's possible without losing the bounty I just assigned to it)

Comment: This question seem better suited at serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any indication that qmail supports LMTP.  Could you redirect to an exim process which runs the LMTP delivery.  This could be configured as a pipe delivery target.  Alternatively, exim could run on another port or server.

Comment: No, I couldn't. I'm trying to avoid installing Postfix/exim/whatever other email server besides qmail.

Comment: As far as I can see from the documentation I have seen you will need a shim of some sort which supports LMTP.  Exim does not need to be run as a mail server.  It can be configured to act only as an MDA.